# Azure Devops query - Group by month

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard

I'd like to create a query which shows the bugs created during the last 12 weeks grouped by each month, but I can't manage.
I have created a query that shows the number of bugs created each day (by date) but can't find a way aggregate them for each month.
Also tried doing it by the chart (Dashboard) but didn't manage as well.
The goal is to show whether the number of bugs gets lower or higher across the last 12 weeks.
Thanks

Comment: As far as I know the best way possible is creating 1-month sprints, Then after  use iteration path variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no built-in feature that an help group by month in query.
In Dashboard, you could choose to use [Burndown/Burnup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops) chart in Dashboard that may meet your requirment. In the configuration, you can add field criteria to limit the work items that appear in the chart. You can set Plot interval to Months. If you select Months, then burndown/burnup is calculated based on the last day of each month.

[image]

You could refer to the official page: [Configure a Burndown or Burnup widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops#choose-the-teams-and-work-items-to-chart) for more details.